# Hide stderr in IntelliJ Idea / PyCharm 'Run' panel?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

Is there a way to toggle the display of `stderr` in the IntelliJ 'Run' tool window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment, please [vote for this feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-134998).